# How to a cast to a String[] in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How do I make this work?

```
user=> (Test/main (object-array ["hello" "world"]))

ClassCastException [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;  user/eval21 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:21)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`object-array` is just used to make arrays of type `Object[]`.   Try `into-array` as you can specify the type (see [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/into-array))

```
> (into-array String ["Awesome","Sauce"])
> #<String[] [Ljava.lang.String;@1b86d76f>
```

Comment: And if you need to create an empty array (i.e, you don't have data yet), use `make-array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def v ["Hello" "World"])
(def a (to-array v))
```

**EDIT:** As @Jeff noted, `into-array` will create typed array (`String[]`) instead of `Object[]`.

Comment: That still produces something of type `Object[]` though - I thought the original question was how to make something of type `string[]`

Comment: @JeffFoster Foster: yeah, I already noticed this :) Can't delete my answer myself, so just upvote to your answer.